# Is there a way to detect a change to the user agent information, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I'd like to display different content based on `window.navigator.userAgent`, but it doesn't seem to be updated when you change it via a browser's devtools.

I want to automatically refresh the page when the user agent is changed using the devtools, to prevent use of a page meant for the actual device/browser instead of the one specified with the devtools.

Comment: The userAgent doesn't change when viewing a website unless you do it via DevTools like you are doing.  Are you wanting the page to react when someone does this in the DevTools?

Comment: Yes that is what I want.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to `window.navigator.userAgent`?

Comment: Yes, is there another way to check it?

Comment: There is no foolproof way of detecting if a user has changed their userAgent. You could store their useragent when they first visit (localstorage) and compare it to detect change, but you have no guarantee that their first visit is their genuine useragent

Comment: @NickSlash, the problem is that an automatic refresh is wanted whenever the user agent is changed. As far as I know, there is no sort of event to detect a change.

Comment: @Enjabain, for a start, `navigator.userAgent` _is_ changed; however, there is no way to detect this change as it happens (i.e., no event or anything is fired; it simply changes). This leaves polling as the only option.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the last paragraph, I thought it was to prevent override the change (keep the initial useragent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userAgent` can only change if the person viewing the site opens up their DevTools and manually changes it. Since this is not really a normal use case, there is no event to watch for when the `userAgent` changes. The **only way** to do this—that I'm aware of—is to manually **poll for changes** (e.g., with `setInterval`):

```js
function uaChanged(prevUa, newUa) {
  console.log('UserAgent changed!');
  console.log('Previous UA:', prevUa);
  console.log('New UA:', newUa);
}

let ua = navigator.userAgent;
setInterval(function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent !== ua) {
    uaChanged(ua, navigator.userAgent);
    ua = navigator.userAgent;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, instead of calling UAChanged(), I did a location.reload(); and it works great.

Comment: Sadly I realized if the user loads the page with a different userAgent changed via devtools before loading the page this does not work.

Comment: Well, that's just how useragent stuff works.  It's part of the browser and the DevTools allow you to change it for development purposes. Once you refresh the page that will not be remembered.  You will have to do whatever changes you need within the currently loaded page

Comment: @Enjabain What about adding a call to `uaChanged` on load? Then any initial setup can be performed, even if the user agent is never actually changed while the page is loaded. Of course, you said you wanted to _refresh_ the page on changes, so it makes sense if everyone thought that the page started out correct for the initial user agent (that behavior is also very logical, else your site would always be displaying the incorrect content).

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` to check periodically to see if it has changed.

```js
let lastUA = null;

setInterval(() => {
  if (navigator.userAgent != lastUA) {
    updateDisplayBasedOnUA();
    lastUA = navigator.userAgent;
  }
}, 500);

let counter = 0;
function updateDisplayBasedOnUA() {
  document.querySelector("#displayCount").innerText = counter++;
  console.log(counter);
}
```

```html
UA changed <span id="displayCount"></span> times
```

Comment: this answer seems pretty much identical to the my accepted answer, but for some reason it did an infinite loop of refreshes.